# Angular 4 function that calls route

Tags: angular, routes

I have routing set up through a menu in my Angular web-app. The menu has routerLinks set up like the home link below:

```
<a routerLink="home">
            <button md-menu-item>
                <md-icon class="material-icons"> home </md-icon>
                <span> Home </span>
            </button>
        </a>
```

The app.router contains:

```
export const router: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
];
```

I want to have a button in a component that redirects to an enquiry form that is not available in the normal menu, but placing an  link on a button in the component does not seem to work. Why is this?

The ideal thing for me to do would be to place a function in an html element in the component that called the route - is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, yes it is of course possible.

Just add Router to your component constructor:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}
```

and then you can call navigate function from Router class in your function which will be called after click on button, for example:

```
this.router.navigate(['home']);
```

Another possibility is to place [routerLink] in html  tag:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/home']">Go To Home</a>
```

Check this:

https://angular.io/guide/router

https://angular.io/api/router/Router

Comment: The a linkway is working fine, but I'd prefer to understand the first method. I'm getting an error saying navigate is not available. Then I import Router, but my app.router only imports Routes and RouterModule - is there a way around this?

Comment: Ok, bizarrely, I seem to have both methods working now - I must have made a syntax error! Thanks for your help :)