# Refresh Header menu after user logged in and after navigate in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using angular and JWT for user authentication which is working good. But after logged in when i user "this.router.navigate(['/blogs']);" then header menu is not refreshing. Still, there is "sign in and signup" links.

I am injecting header and footer component in app.component like:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

and in routing :

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'blogs', component: BlogsComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard] },
  {
    path: 'signup', component: UserComponent,
    children: [{ path: '', component: SignUpComponent }]
  },
  {
    path: 'login', component: UserComponent,
    children: [{ path: '', component: SignInComponent }]
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }

];
```

I also used service to check user logged in or not but it's not working with navigating. When I refresh then it is working fine.

Please suggest.

Comment: Make your `app-header` user-aware

Comment: Please explain little bit more

Comment: try this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46044392/angular-4-function-that-calls-route

Comment: This is not my issue. I am navigating properly But after this unable to update menu links.

Comment: 1.)have multiple header's and conditionally set a variable based on authentication in app.component.ts while routing(subscribe to router) say `template: `
    `<app-header *ngIf="loggedIn"></app-header>  <router-outlet></router-outlet>`
2.)use emit after route change and update the variable.